# define a function with string but do not execute it (no eval,etc...more like include,require)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'd like to ask you for a help because I'm at dead end...

I'm using google sheet script editor and I'm trying to create a custom menu with custom functions. However I want to achieve it as library that can be connected to other sheets for other users and it will update automatically when I make a new version. Problem begins when I want to define it as "custom function" to the menu.

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addSubMenu(
        ui.createMenu('clipboard')
          .addItem('copy', 'menuItem1')
          .addItem('paste', 'menuItem2')
      )
      .addToUi();



function menuItem1(){
  bla,bla,bla
}
function menuItem2(){
  bla,bla,bla
}
```

In menu I can declare only the function name but that means whenever there's a new function in a menu, user has to manually put it in.

```
ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addSubMenu(
        ui.createMenu('clipboard')
          .addItem('copy', 'menuItem1')
          .addItem('paste', 'menuItem2')
      )
      .addSeparator()
      .addSubMenu(
        ui.createMenu('merge')
          .addItem('merge', 'menuItem3')
          .addItem('unmerge', 'menuItem4')
      )
      .addToUi();


function menuItem1(){
  bla,bla,bla
}
function menuItem2(){
  bla,bla,bla
}
function menuItem3(){
  bla,bla,bla
}
function menuItem4(){
  bla,bla,bla
}
```

I do not want that. I want to create a list of functions and then somehow include it in to the file automatically when I update my library...but I can not include it in google script editor also when I'm using library I have to use library mark name

`ml = MyLibrary then ml.menuItem1.`

I have to use only

`menuItem1` and not `ml.menuItem1`

I'm looking for a way to include this file somehow but best that I could thought of was to define function from string but do not execute it.

```
function listOfFunctions(){
  var functionString1 = "function menuItem1(){ blablabla }";

  var functionString2 = "function menuItem1(){ blablabla }";
    return functionString1 + functionString2;
}
```

then somehow parse it to:

```
function menuItem1(){ blablabla };
```

and then execute it when I want.

`menuItem1()` or `menuItem2()`

If I run this string thru eval() the function Will get executed and I just want to define it. I can execute it later with triggers.

Sooooo you think of any help please???

Comment: You really should remove all the unrelated google sheets stuff et. al. and narrow down the problem. No one wants to read text this long

Comment: If the user changes the version number of the library, then whatever changes you made in the new published version will be used.  If you added menu items in the new published version, then they will show up.  If you want to show new menu items without publishing a new version, and without the user changing the version number, then you'd need to get the menu items from some external source, like a spreadsheet, text file, or database.  But then the user would need to authorize accessing an external url.  Are your users all in the same domain?  Like a GSuite account in your company?

Comment: Your code here uses Spreadsheet Service / UI functionality as global variables. That's a terrible idea. Any and every time any new script execution starts, those all execute.

Comment: SOLVED!!! I'm returning the full function definition as string `function returnFunctionAsString(){var string = "function test(){blablabla}"}` and then just thru `eval(returnFunctionAsString())` after that I can call it whenever I want...It works like include or require...I can call the functions later on...I swear I tried it yesterday and when I put returnFunctionAsString thru eval() I got this function also executed straight away. Thanks guys for all replies, it also helped me a lot and got to use it elsewhere :)